# Getting 400 Bad Request while calling RestAPI in eclipse, but working in Postman

Tags: java, http-status-code-400, httpconnection, 400-bad-request

I have a function which takes `2` input -

1. `JSON` filepath
2. RestURL

After calling the function, it should return the output as `JSON`.

But the problem here, it is throwing `400` Bad request error.
Below is the log of error which i am getting -

```
Error Log :
URL:
http://localhost:26081/jderest/v3/orchestrator/ORC_2212160001JDE
Conn : sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://localhost:26081/jderest/v3/orchestrator/ORC_2212160001JDE
JSON Input path : \\phxxxx155826.xxxxxx.fusionappsdphx1.xxxxxxxx.com\\FF\\Orchest\\orc1.json
{
"username": "ic8823790",
"password": "ic8823790",
"Product_No": "sss265",
"Description": "sss265",
"Stocking_Type": "s",
"G_L_Class": "in30",
"Unit_of_Measure": "ea",
"Search_Text": "sss265",
"Branch_Plant": "30"
}
HTTP CODE : 400
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://exx11001.ad1.xxxxxxxdephx.xxxxxxx.com:26081/jderest/v3/orchestrator/ORC_2212160001JDE
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1939)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1938)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1508)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at OrchestratorAPI.orchestratorCall(OrchestratorAPI.java:108)
at OrchestratorAPI.main(OrchestratorAPI.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://ems11001.ad1.fusionappsdephx.oraclevcn.com:26081/jderest/v3/orchestrator/ORC_2212160001JDE
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at OrchestratorAPI.orchestratorCall(OrchestratorAPI.java:100)
... 1 more
```

This is source what i have tried -

```
public class OrchestratorAPI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String filepath = "\\\\xxxxxxx155826.xxxxxxx.fusionappsdphx1.xxxxxxx.com\\FF\\Orchest\\orc1.json";
        String orchAPI = "http://exx11001.ad1.xxxxxxxdephx.xxxxxxx.com:26081/jderest/v3/orchestrator/ORC_2212160001JDE";
        orchestratorCall(filepath, orchAPI);
    
    }
    
    public static void orchestratorCall(String filePath, String orchestAPI) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        StringBuilder result;
        String content = "";
        String path = "", sid = "";
        String paramsJSON="";
    
        URLConnection con = new URL(orchestAPI).openConnection();
        System.out.println("URL : "+orchestAPI + "\nConn : "+con);
    
        System.out.println("JSON Input path : " + filePath);
        try {
            paramsJSON = new String(
                Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        System.out.println(paramsJSON);
    
        try {
            ((HttpURLConnection) con).setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setReadTimeout(60000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    
            try (OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
                byte[] input = paramsJSON.getBytes(charset);
                os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            }
    
            int code = ((HttpURLConnection) con).getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("HTTP CODE : " + String.valueOf(code));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        try {
            // Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
    
            System.out.println("JSON Parser -> result: " + result.toString());
    
            try {
                // Create new report file
                content = result.toString();
                path = "\\\\xxxxxxx155826.xxxxxxx.fusionappsdphx1.xxxxxxxx.com\\FF\\Orchest\\" + "" + "OrchestratorReport.json";
                System.out.println("Home Dir path : " + path);
                File file = new File(path);
    
                // If file doesn't exists, then create it
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
    
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    
                // Write in file
                bw.write(content);
    
                // Close connection
                bw.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        ((HttpURLConnection) con).disconnect();   
    }
}
```

Comment: The client code looks ok to me. What matters is the backend. Do you have the code for that? You said it's working with postman, how are you sending the request there? POST? Which headers? How are you sending the request body?

Comment: I am using POST request to call the API. Request body is a raw JSON like this-
{
"username": "ic8823790",
"password": "ic8823790",
"Product_No": "sss265",
"Description": "sss265",
"Stocking_Type": "s",
"G_L_Class": "in30",
"Unit_of_Measure": "ea",
"Search_Text": "sss265",
"Branch_Plant": "30"
}
@invzbl3

Answer (score 0):

the issue is solved.
I have just removed the `UTF-8` from the `setRequestProperty` of the connection and it is working now.

Before :

```java
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
```

After :

```java
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```